# Interact with web browser using Qt/bash script?

Tags: c++, bash, qt, selenium, browser

I frequently need to access to the router to do some simple task: restart, switch on/off some options... And the repeated process really annoying me :(

I want to write a batch script/program which do it for me.

I can't flash the router with the DD-WRT firmware to access it via console. The policy don't allow it.

Then I come up with an idea that use Qt write a small program which will interact with the browser. Access the router IP, fill the password, browse to the option page...

However, AFAIK, I can only do such thing with a web-driver like selenium, which is unavailable with Qt.

So is there any solution? I really like the idea use Qt or a script to solve the problem.

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: I can try to load the web page into a `QWebFrame` and invoke a JavaScript script with `QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript()` that will do something on that page.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Like a pseudo or something? I get your idea but can't imagine the check-list what to do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to just send form response and don't load the page in the QWebFrame. You can use some tool (firebug, wireshark) to catch the request/response when you click "save" and learn what to send to your router everytime you want this configuration. **It will be simple HTTP GET or POST request.** That request can be done with curl, wget or your simple QT application using QNetworkRequest or wethewer.

It will be more tricky if it needs authentification other then HTTP basic auth. You will need two requests

- first one - authenticate and save all cookies
- second one - set parameters and add all cookies to response

Comment: I feel your instruction is very close to the goal. I test it with a TPLINK router (html and javascript),the firewall `save` button call `SecurityRpm.htm?stat=1792&Save=Save`. Is there any different if the router use ASP (wrt54gl) ?

Comment: And another problem is the authentication, I use `Chrome DevTools` and find the router left nothing after a successful login: cookie, session, local storage, cache...

Comment: It is possible that there is some "session" in get parameter e.g. stat=1792

Comment: Hi, I managed to find the router use `basic authentication` which I can handle. The `stats` is kind of a setting state variable, I guess.

Last question: do you thing is there any different if the router pages are written is ASP rather than html and javascript?

Comment: You don't need to know anything about what is used. HTTP request you are composing does not use HTML nor javascript. In your situation, it is also not important what is running on server side - ASP, PHP or whatever.

Comment: Thank, I did what I need, like you say: they're the same :)